# How to disallow particular fields to be specified when inserting a new row into an SqLite table?

Tags: sqlite, triggers

Some fields in an SqLite 3 table I am to deal with have default values computed dynamically for every new row being inserted and this is what is meant to be done with every insert without exceptions. But it actually is enough to specify theese fields values explicitly together with other fields values and these get recorded into the DB instead of what what was meant to be computed.

What is the correct form of a trigger that would either abort inserts with certain fields values not omitted or just discard these values letting the defaults defined to be used instead?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to tell apart a default value from a value that was explicitly specified and happens to have the same value as the default value.

Furthermore, it is not possible to change what an INSERT statement will insert (except with an additional UPDATE statement).

The best you can do is a trigger that checks that all those inserted values are identical with the default values:

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable (
    Name TEXT,
    Date DATE DEFAULT CURRENT_DATE
);

CREATE TRIGGER MyTable_CheckDefaultDate
BEFORE INSERT ON MyTable
WHEN ifnull(NEW.Date, '') <> CURRENT_DATE
BEGIN
    SELECT RAISE(FAIL, "date must be default");
END;
```